Comment écrire correctemment « Shomal » en français ?
En Iran, la région du Nord s'appelle « Shomal » (شمال en Farsi).
Pouvez-vous m'indiquer la translittération correcte en français ?
« Shomal » ou « Chomal » ?

Aucune des deux formes n'est incorrecte.
On peut prendre comme exemple شاه qui est retranscrit en français shah, chah et même parfois schah.
La recommandation serait d'écrire Chomal mais elle est discutable car la prononciation du digramme ch est ambiguë en français (il se prononce généralement [ʃ] mais, dans certains cas, la prononciation peut être [k] (mots d'origine grecque ou italienne) ou [t͡ʃ] (en particulier les mots d'origine espagnole ou anglaise).
Le choix du digramme sh, même s'il n'est pas historiquement français, a le mérite de ne pas souffrir de cette ambiguïté car il se prononce toujours [ʃ].
